# RetrieveSalesforceObjects with date filter - Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to consult Salesforce records that where created in the last 7 days, but when I test the email it appears the following error:

> Call to retrieve records for salesforceobject Questionario__c failed! 
>   Error in the application.
>   API Fault: Salesforce.com Fault thrown.
>   Exception Type:MalformedQueryFault
>   Exception Code:MALFORMED_QUERY
>   Exception Message: '0010U000003EkpkQAC' AND LastModifiedDate >
>   12/25/2017 4:31:35 ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:223 unexpected token: / At
>   row:1 and column: 223

```
%%[

set @id = Id

set @today = now()

set @setedias = dateadd(@today,'-6','D')


set @Questfinalizado1 = retrievesalesforceobjects('Questionario__c','Pesquisador__c,Status_do_Questionario__c,LastModifiedDate','Status_do_Questionario__c','=','Pendente de Análise VIDI','Pesquisador__c','=',@id)

set @Questfinalizado2 = retrievesalesforceobjects('Questionario__c','Pesquisador__c,Status_do_Questionario__c,LastModifiedDate','Status_do_Questionario__c','=','Em Aprovação','Pesquisador__c','=',@id)

set @Questfinalizado3 = retrievesalesforceobjects('Questionario__c','Pesquisador__c,Status_do_Questionario__c,Data_alteracao_status__c,LastModifiedDate','Status_do_Questionario__c','=','Aprovado','Pesquisador__c','=',@id,'LastModifiedDate','>',@setedias)


set @countfinalizado1 = rowcount(@Questfinalizado1)

set @countfinalizado2 = rowcount(@Questfinalizado2)

set @countfinalizado3 = rowcount(@Questfinalizado3)

set @totalfinal = add(@countfinalizado1,@countfinalizado2)

set @totalfinalizado = add(@totalfinal,@countfinalizado3)

]%%
```

When I test it whithout the **'LastModifiedDate','>',@setedias** criteria it runs normally.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try hard fixing a date on `setedias` and see if that works (try different formats and values:

```
set @setedias = '01/01/2018'
```

if passing in a hardcoded date works (if you find a working format) then you're going in the right direction. Then you could play about with a `FormatDate` function.

```
set @setedias = formatdate(dateadd(@today,'-6','D'), "MMM dd, yyyy", "HH:mm:ss.tt", "en-US")
```

My gut tells me it's something to do with your date format lookup on `LastModifiedDate`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
set @setedias = FORMATDATE(dateadd(@today,'-6','D'), "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:mm:ss.000Z")
```